# RSForm filter submissions using submission directory on frontend

Tags: rsform

I have created a form using RSForm pro and my users can submit their information with this form. One of the form fields named "age". There are three admins in my site. They should see and check users submissions. They see the submissions in front-end using [Submissions Directory Menu Item](https://www.rsjoomla.com/support/documentation/rsform-pro/getting-started/submissions-directory-menu-item.html). The issue is that the submissions should be filtered for each admin.

For example the first admin should see only submissions that the "age" field value is between 20 and 30. The second admin should see only submissions that the "age" field value is between 31 and 40. And finally the third admin should see only submissions that the "age" field value is between 41 and 50.

How I filter the submissions according to logged in admin?

Comment: Thank you for joining us.  Please take our [tour] while you wait for support from our volunteer base.

Comment: You're probably going to need a custom PHP script added to the section named `Scripts called on listing layout`. The `$directoryLayout` string contains the HTML code of the directory listing page. Your PHP script will need to check the id of the logged in user, then populate a table based on the results.